# PHP ssh2_exec channel exit status?

Tags: php, ssh, pecl

Ok, so pecl ssh2 is supposedly a wrapper for libssh2.  libssh2 has libssh2_channel_get_exit_status.  Is there ANY way to get this information?

I NEED:
-STDOUT
-STDERR
-EXIT STATUS

I get all but exit status.  A lot of people throw around phplibsec when ssh is brought up, but I see no way of getting stderr or the channel exit status out of that either:/  Has anybody been able to get all three?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, first thing is first:
NO, they didn't implement libssh2_channel_get_exit_status.  Why?  Beyond me.
Here is what id did:

```
$command .= ';echo -e "\n$?"'
```

I cram a newline and echo of $? onto the end of every command I exec.  Rangy?  Yes.  But it seems to have worked out rather well.  I then pull that off into $returnValue and strip all the newlines off the end of stdout.  Maybe someday getting the channel's exit status will be supported, and a few years after that it will be in the distro repos.  For now, this has been good enough.  When your running 30+ remote commands to populate complex remote resources, this is much, much better than setting up and tearing down the ssh session for each command.

Comment: If the command is `exit 1`, the echo wont be run. `$command = '(' . $command . ');echo -e "\n$?"'` might be better.

Answer (score 7):

I tried to improve upon Rapzid's answer a bit more. For my purposed I wrapped ssh2 in a php object and implemented these two functions. It allows me to handle the ssh errors using sane exception catching.

```
function exec( $command )
{
    $result = $this->rawExec( $command.';echo -en "\n$?"' );
    if( ! preg_match( "/^(.*)\n(0|-?[1-9][0-9]*)$/s", $result[0], $matches ) ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( "output didn't contain return status" );
    }
    if( $matches[2] !== "0" ) {
        throw new RuntimeException( $result[1], (int)$matches[2] );
    }
    return $matches[1];
}

function rawExec( $command )
{
    $stream = ssh2_exec( $this->_ssh2, $command );
    $error_stream = ssh2_fetch_stream( $stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDERR );
    stream_set_blocking( $stream, TRUE );
    stream_set_blocking( $error_stream, TRUE );
    $output = stream_get_contents( $stream );
    $error_output = stream_get_contents( $error_stream );
    fclose( $stream );
    fclose( $error_stream );
    return array( $output, $error_output );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since version 0.13 of the SSH2 PHP extension, you can use `stream_get_meta_data()` to retrieve the exit staus.

With the code of your example:

```php
// $connection is a SSH2 connection created with ssh2_connect()
// $command is the command you want to execute
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, $command);
$metadata = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
$exitCode = $metadata['exit_status'];
```