# PHP Net_SSH2 - exec() how to get the command return code

Tags: php, ssh, exec, phpseclib

How can I get the return code for the command that is executed :

```
<?php
include('Net/SSH2.php');

$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');
if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) {
    exit('Login Failed');
}

echo $ssh->exec('cat /tmp/file_tmp');
//verify the return code
echo $ssh->exec('echo $?');

?>
```

`echo $?`(Linux) and `echo %errorlevel%`(Win) don't work.

Any Ideas??

Comment: Have you tried to prepend `2>&1` ?

Comment: I am new at this. I dont know how i can use `2>&1`.

Comment: Does your /tmp/file_tmp record your return correctly ? Is it empty ? if not please could you send its content

Comment: its does not exist. i am expecting error code. the output is `cat: cannot open /tmp/file_tmp`

Comment: `2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout. It doesn't give you the "return code".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found one option (a workaround).
[PHP ssh2_exec channel exit status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10478491/php-ssh2-exec-channel-exit-status)

The below code worked for me, serves my purpose:

```
$command .= ';echo "[return_code:$?]"';
$output = $ssh->exec($command);
preg_match( '/\[return_code:(.*?)\]/', $output, $match );
$return_code = $match[1];
echo "\r\n". $output;
echo "\r\n".$return_code;
```

Thanks everyone for your inputs. Appreciate it!!

Comment: for windows, i have put together this:  `(your_command.exe && IF ERRORLEVEL 0 echo pass) || echo fail`

Comment: Even if the other answer is correct (there's the $ssh->getExisStatus() method), in Laravel that I'm using the method is not accessible, so your answer solved my problem. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

Does `$ssh->getExitStatus()` do what you're wanting?

Comment: this gives the exit code of ssh Exec. if the command was executed or not. this does not denote the command exit code.

Comment: It seems that it actually returns the exit code of the last executed command,